# My NVIDIA X Server Settings not showing

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, xserver, nvidia-prime, nvidia-settings

So right now I only have 2 tabs in my settings. There the ones in this picture.

[image: NVIDIA X Server Settings]

I have reinstalled the drivers numerous times, but that does not help. I have also tried other driver versions. I have searched the internet and have found a lot of problems like mine but answers on here did not fix it.

The Graphics Card is a GTX 1050 Ti and I am kinda a beginner with Linux so any help would be appreciated. Oh also I am running xUbuntu

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the nvidia drivers to the latest versions like 390 etc. Also, try sudo update-pciids and reboot, which updates the ID of existing GPU machine.

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)